# Android java I want to use my filtred datalist?

Tags: java, android, filter, android-recyclerview

How to get filtered list after filtering ?

Comment: What do you want to do with filtered list?

Comment: I need to know how many they are

Comment: getCount() gives you the count right..!!. You want to display it somewhere?

Comment: no getCount() gives me my main datalist count!!

Comment: you implemented this?
@Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return filteredList.size();
    }

Comment: Sorry bro but this is not the solution :(

Comment: Similar to that create you own method that returns your filterable list size. It should work..!!